# Java swing timer not delaying other commands

Tags: java, swing

i am pretty new to java ( about a year of self teaching ) so i have a question.

Im making a poker game implementing a full gui to go along with it. I have a JTextArea that i use for all output ( kind of like a live console output ). Ive used the following,

```
private void printer(String s, int delay){
    messageDelay = new Timer( delay, new ActionListener(){
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
              dealerText.append("Dealer>> " + s + "\n");
          }
        } );
    messageDelay.setRepeats( false );
    messageDelay.start();
}
```

And then called the method here,

```
private void runGame(){
    printer("Dealing Cards...", 2000);

    firstCard.setVisible(true);
    secondCard.setVisible(true);
```

I want the cards to be shown after the 2 second delay but they are instantly appearing. I know theres a problem here i just am not sure how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `setVisible(true)` calls should be in `Timer` in `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak i was hoping to use printer as a universal way of delaying the messages, not just for 1 instance

Comment: Only the code inside `actionPerformed` method is delayed. Add `System.out.println` inside this method and next to where you call `setVisible` and see when they are printed.

Comment: I know @JaroslawPawlak, thats why i'm asking how to delay this message then continue running commands. Thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

using a `Timer`, you can not delay the main thread. The delay time works only inside of code blocks of `actionPerformed` method.

If you want to delay your main thread before `firstCard.setVisible(true);` code line, you can code it like this.

```
private void runGame(){
    printer("Dealing Cards...", 2000);

    Thread.sleep(nDelay);
    firstCard.setVisible(true);
    secondCard.setVisible(true);
```

Or you can do it like this. But both `firstCard` and `secondCard` visibilities will be set regularly. If you don't change their visibilities in another code line, It doesn't make sense so I would use the former solution for it.

```
private void printer(String s, int delay){
    messageDelay = new Timer( delay, new ActionListener(){
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
              dealerText.append("Dealer>> " + s + "\n");

              firstCard.setVisible(true);
              secondCard.setVisible(true);
          }
        } );
    messageDelay.setRepeats( false );
    messageDelay.start();
}
```

Comment: The former method seems to make the whole GUI freeze for the nDelay time, and in terms of the second method, i am using the printer method to print other things further on in the gui